# laravel charts not showing data called from view composer

Tags: laravel

I hope to find solution here.
I'm using laravel 5.6 and laravel charts from: 
 https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts

My problem is :

I created a chart with data from database from a controller and I show it in a view and it works fine.
Now I wanted to show this chart into another view, so I decided to put the variable which contains the chart in a View composer after creating composer service provider.

When I put in simple data then it is rendered perfectly but when I put the chart variable it is not rendered as a graphic chart but as a code with tags.
This is the code rendered :

```
<canvas style="display: none;" id="tfypgmkjwulqasnhcxbdozive" height='400' ></canvas>
<div id="tfypgmkjwulqasnhcxbdozive_loader" style=" display: flex; justify-content: center; opacity: 1; align-items: center; height: 400px; ">
   <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 38 38" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
         <linearGradient x1="8.042%" y1="0%" x2="65.682%" y2="23.865%" id="a">
            <stop stop-color="#22292F" stop-opacity="0" offset="0%"/>
            <stop stop-color="#22292F" stop-opacity=".631" offset="63.146%"/>
            <stop stop-color="#22292F" offset="100%"/>
         </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
         <g transform="translate(1 1)">
            <path d="M36 18c0-9.94-8.06-18-18-18" id="Oval-2" stroke="url(#a)" stroke-width="2">
               <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 18 18" to="360 18 18" dur="0.9s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </path>
            <circle fill="#22292F" cx="36" cy="18" r="1">
               <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 18 18" to="360 18 18" dur="0.9s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </circle>
         </g>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

I'm struggling these days but in vain thank u for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you sure view composer working?
check it using dd() in view file

Comment: yes it works fine with simple data like authenticated user : Auth::user()->name;

Comment: i mean check view composer data available in your view or not

Comment: data shoud be shown as a chart not as a code like mentionned